# Umbraco and YAF

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, yetanotherforum

I am trying to use YAF with Umbraco.  The newest version out changed enough where the old integration methods don't seem to work.  I have gotten everything fairly far on my own but I have hit a brick wall with this error:

Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Source Error: 


Line 23:     <img src="~/yaf/images/YAFLogo.jpg" runat="server" alt="YetAnotherForum" id="imgBanner" /><br/>    
Line 24:     <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Line 25:         <YAF:Forum runat="server" ID="yafForum" />
Line 26:     </form>
Line 27: </body>
```

I have a feeling that YAF is not starting up the database.  In previous versions of YAF there was an INIT module that you loaded in your web.config file.  This module is no longer there (YAF.Base.YAFInitModule).

Comment: According to the head dude at YAF, it might be a permissions issue ( http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/yaf_postsm42916_Umbraco-and-YAF.aspx#post42916 ) but I am not sure what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't come up with this but here is the solution from http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/11233-Umbraco-and-YAF?p=0:

Make sure your YAF installtion is really accessible. I know this sounds kind of odd, but I

> had to alter YAF.FileRoot and
>   YAF.AppRoot several times until I got
>   it up and running again - see
>   app.config). The best way to test this
>   is to overwrite your main web.config
>   (the one from Umbraco with the default
>   web.config from YAF.Net and see if you
>   get the forum running in the subfolder
>   (or folder structure) For test
>   purposes you might have to temporarily
>   remove Form.browser from your
>   App_Browser directory as this file
>   caused a lot of parsing errors when I
>   only ran YAF.Net (which is pretty
>   clear as we do not have the right
>   references) Remove Umbraco Channels
>   path="umbraco/channels.aspx"
>   path="umbraco/channels/word.aspx" from
>   the web.config as they use a different
>   CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll than
>   YAF.Net does (apparently Umbraco uses
>   still a pretty old version)

Umbraco and YAF also differ in the CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll file.  Umbraco uses 2.2.0.4 while YAF uses 2.4.0.0.  You need to deploy the 2.4.0.0 version to your server's GAC to get this working right

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to run YAF in a .net 4.0 environment. The YAF assemblies, however, are built in .net 2.0. This could be the cause of your problems.

You can download the YAF source and change the project's properties to build to .net 4.0 instead.

Comment: Hmmm...I thought that 4.0 was backwards compatible

Comment: Oh no, it's a whole new runtime. In fact, as per the instructions on installing YAF, you'd apparently have to do a build for 3.5 as well, even though it's an extension of 2.0. Not sure why that would be the case though..

Comment: That ended up creating more issues.  I have contacted the owners of YAF to see if they can help me.

Comment: Turns out it was something else http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/11233-Umbraco-and-YAF?p=1 .